# findout and override vcpkg build toolchain

Tags: package, toolchain, vcpkg

when vcpkg install  is used? which toolchain is used to build the package being installed?
How the tool chain is inferred? Is it possible to override it with preferred toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/triplets/

look at `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`

other things you might want to look into: `--overlay-triplets`

Comment: Let me try setting up those variables, thanks for the link.